# How to visualize Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I change the border color for my Contact Form 7? At the moment it is yellow, but I would like something else.

How can I can archive this?

[current contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7turd.png)

This part of code for the contact form but, but I didn't find any way that I can insert my color code.

```
<div class="request_callback">
<div class="row_1">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="width:33%;">
        <div class="input-group">
            [text* name placeholder akismet:author "Name"]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="width:33%;">
        <div class="input-group">
            [tel* phone placeholder "Phone number"]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="width:33%;">
        <div class="input-group">
            [text* email placeholder "Email"]
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- END: row_1-->
<div class="row_2">       
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="width:100%">
        <div class="input-group" >
            [select* services_consulting first_as_label "Model" "All" "Coral" "Coral Mini" "Mini Water Bar" "Faucet" "Master Filter" "Water bar S6"]
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can handle it with css as you have separate main class for your form is this .request_callback so you can add css like something on active

```
.request_callback input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text:active{

     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

can you paste your url so I can send more correct css.